# Exchange of informations between classes in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, object, compiler-errors

I've got two problems:

First: I'm getting  `StackOverflowError` and I don't know how to fix it

Second: I'm using similar syntax in other projects and there was no problems with `StackOverflowError`. The second problem is in comments in my code. I want to change value of `x` in class `ChangeValueOfVariable` and use it in class `DisplayValueOfVariable`.

```
class DisplayValueOfVariable{
    ChangeValueOfVariable change = new ChangeValueOfVariable();
    public int x = 0;

    public void showX(){
        System.out.println("Value of x: "+x); //There is still x = 0
    }

    public void changedX(){
        change.changeValue();
        System.out.println("Value of x: " +x);  // Unfortunately there is still x = 0, but I want here to use changed value 
    }
}

class ChangeValueOfVariable{
    DisplayValueOfVariable disp = new DisplayValueOfVariable();

    public void changeValue(){
    disp.x++;
    System.out.println("Value of x: "+disp.x); // Now x = 1
    }
}


class Start{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayValueOfVariable displayValueOfVariable = new DisplayValueOfVariable();
    displayValueOfVariable.showX();
    displayValueOfVariable.changedX();
    }
}
```

I know, that I can change `x` in `public void changedX()`, but if I will have more variables it wouldn't help me in cleaning my code.

Thanks for your help ;)

I know that if I'll make something like this

```
class DisplayValueOfVariable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        System.out.println(x);
        x++;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

It will be my expected result, ok.

I understand that if I will use only one class(which I attached), my code would compile without errors and code would be simpler.
Unfortunately I have to split my code and save it as more classes.
I've got problem with operations(in other classes) on already existing variables.

Comment: You have cyclic references, both classes reference and create instances of the other. Don't do this. Instead pass instances in.

Comment: You mean I should extend one class by another?

Comment: Oh heavens, no, not at all. You need to give at least one of those classes a setter method and set the reference. Please read the duplicates as it's all well explained there.

Comment: The way you've set this up, whenever a new `DisplayValueOfVariable` object is created, the next thing that happens is that a new `ChangeValueOfVariable` object is also created.  But also,  whenever a new `ChangeValueOfVariable` object is created, the next thing that happens is that a new `DisplayValueOfVariable` object is also created.  So, loosely speaking, your computer is busy creating more and more objects until it runs out of stack space.

Comment: I suspect you want just one of each type of object.  An even better design would be to have a single class, not two of them.

Comment: I don't get it - solution in duplicate. I had to make setter with this:       `public void setChange(ChangeValueOfVariable change) {
        this.change = change;
    }`
 Yes, I want create two objects only once. Having single class is easier than make two, but I've got 450-500 lines of code in my project and I want to clean this mess, because it's hard to read this.

Comment: So, if you get rid of the `ChangeValueOfVariable`  class, and move its method to the `DisplayValueOfVariable` class, all your troubles will go away.

Comment: I've just edit my post. I think there is reply, why I'm not interested to make only one class - I've got it and I need some advices, how to split my code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand the new paragraph at the end at all.

Comment: Now it's better? :)